# PHP code that sends automatically email and stores it in MYSQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

At first,
im just at the beginning of programming and i dont speak that good english.

I want to code a program that sends automatically a email to a person AND stores the data into a MYSQL table.

This is my HTML code what i need to send per mail to a colleague and store the data into a MYSQL table.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
<title>Formular</title>
 <body>
  <h1>Arufmitteilung<h1>
   <h2>Ansprechpartner/in</h2>
    <form method="post" action="anrufmitteilung.php">
    <input type="text" name="Ansprechpartner/in" list="mitarbeiter">
    <h2>Name des Anrufers</h2>
    <form method="post" action="anrufmitteilung.php">
    <input type="text" name="Name des Anrufers">
   <h2>Firmenname</h2>
    <form method="post" action="anrufmitteilung.php">
    <input type="text" name="Firmenname">
   <h2>Telefonnummer des Anrufers</h2>
    <form method="post" action="anrufmitteilung.php">
    <input type="text" name="Telefonnummer des Anrufers">
   <h2>Grund des Anrufs</h2>
    <form method="post" cols="50" rows="8" action="anrufmitteilung.php">
    <input type="text" name="Grund des Anrufs">
   <h2>Anruf entgegengenommen von</h2>
    <form method="post" action="anrufmitteilung.php">
    <input type= "text" name="Anruf entgegengenommen von" list="mitarbeiter">
    <input type="submit" value="Abschicken">
    </form>
 </body>
<datalist id="mitarbeiter"> 
 <option value="Max Mustermann">
 <option value="Max Mustermann2">
 <option value="Max Mustermann3">
 <option value="Max Mustermann4">
 <option value="Max Mustermann5">
 <option value="Max Mustermann6">
 <option value="Max Mustermann7">
 <option value="Max Mustermann8">
 <option value="Max Mustermann9">
 <option value="Max Mustermann10">
</datalist>
</html>
```

So now i dont know how the PHP code need to look like.

Can some1 help me?

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Please update your answer with some of the PHP that youve tried to get working.

Comment: It's about 2 separate things to do: interact with the database (PHP-mysql) and send an email (PHP-email). Now I suggest you to start studying PHP making an example of each interaction, maybe a script inserting a dummy record in database and a script sending email, then try to put all together, and if you don't succeed, after some trials, post here. This isn't the place in which others make the work for you ground-up.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should try to investigate the mail() function in php, investigate how to connect to a database with mysql, see how to upload data. These are individual things you should be doing, not asking someone to write it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you won't be able to do anything with the HTML alone, here are some tips...

1. You will need to create a file which connects to your database
2. You will have to create a script which handles your data after submitting the form. This can be done with **Post** request. Something like:  `if (isset($_POST['name']))`
3. In the script where you handle the data, you will have to do a **query**. Something like: `INSERT INTO (table_name) (column_names) VALUES (corresponding data)`. Also, this should be done with mysqli_* or via PDO...
4. After saving the data into the database, you can create a body for your mail, and send it via the `mail()` function in php

I hope this will give you an idea and some google work.